# Number of attempts to reach $X$ probability of a random event happening $N$ times

Tags: probability

I have a random event that has a low chance $p$ of happening every step of my simulation.
I want to get the number of steps to get the probability of that event happening $n$ times at $q$ probability.

I think I figured out how to calculate how to calculate for that if the event is only supposed to happen once
$\log(1 - q) / \log(1 - p)$
but I am not sure of even that. I thought of replacing $p$ by $p^n$ but I'm not sure if that will achieve this.

Note that the events are completely independent of one another.

Comment: I am trying to figure out at what number of steps (or tries) I would reach the target probability of the event happing N times

Comment: As a rule, when talking probabilities, capital letters mean random variables, lower case mean real numbers. So your variables here should all be lower case. Preferably, probabilities should be called $p,q,r$ or some variant. $x$ and $y$ should be replaced with $p,q.$ $n$ should be fine for the third variable.

Comment: Okay, I will edit this then ! I'm quite new to probabilities, so I'm kind of guessing how to correctly ask / show my question

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect this is hard to compute. If $p$ is the probability of the single event, the probability you get $n$ or more events in $m$ turns us: $$q_m=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom mk p^k(1-p)^{m-k}$$ This is notoriously difficult to compute. You can  maybe find a recursion for $q_m$ which makes it easier to compute.

Comment: This helps a bit, but I'm trying to solve for $m$. This I could try to solve this recursively, but this might also be very difficult to compute as my chance of a single event happening is very low, and the fact that I have to compute that for several similar instances.

Comment: @firestorck Can you use a normal approximation for the binomial distribution?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I've never heard of that so I'm not sure, I'll read on that to see if I can apply it here

Comment: @firestorck Is the event occurring exactly $n$ times or at least $n$ times?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio It must be happening at least $n$ times, as in my simulator rules it cannot happen after that, so even if it was supposed to happen more, the extra would simply be ignored

Comment: @firestorck Yeah, that's why I said it was hard. You won't find a closed form, I'd bet.

Comment: @firestorck Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) for an approximation

Comment: From what I understand, a normal approximation uses a phew starting iterations to create a model for a normal curve which then allows to just "pick out" an approximation of what you want. Would making a derivation of that where instead of tracing a normal curve, we trace the sum of all previous normal values (which would then tend to 1 instead of 0) be possible, thus making such an approximation possible ? it would look something like the green line [here](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/7/79/OptimalGrowth.png/revision/latest?cb=20190714223110)

Comment: @firestorck It would use the inverse CDF of a standard normal...I can write it out in an answer if you want

Comment: @Golden_Ratio yeah, that'd be of great help! I also got some reading to do to understand this now x)

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve the number of trials $m$ where $1-P(X\leq n-1)=q$ where $X\sim Bin(m,p)$, a binomial random variable with $m$ trials and probability of success $p$.

Letting $Z$ represent a standard normal random variable and $\Phi$ its associated CDF, using a [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) gives us

$$P(X\leq n-1)\approx P\left(Z\leq {n-1-mp\over \sqrt{mp(1-p)}} \right)=\Phi \left({n-1-mp\over \sqrt{mp(1-p)}} \right).$$

Setting the right hand side to $1-q$ gives a quadratic in $m$ to solve for. Your solution will be expressed in terms of $\Phi^{-1}(1-q).$

However, a normal approximation may not be the best if $p$ is extreme or $n$ is small. You can also apply a "continuity correction." See the wiki link for details and caveats.